# Java Generate Random Values Between 1500 and 1650 Inclusive

Tags: java, random

I am looking to generate random integers between the values of 1500 and 1650 inclusive.

I have successfully generated random values between 25 and 55 inclusive (code below).  The problem that I am having, however, is that if I adapt the code to generate a value between 1500 and 1650 inclusive, the result ends up providing me with the value `1500` very often as most numbers that are generated are below that, and my `if` statement sets anything that is below 1500 to 1500.

```
Random rand = new Random();

    double angle = rand.nextInt(55);
    if(angle < 25){
        angle = 25;
    }

    double muzzlevelocity = rand.nextInt(1500) + 150;

    if(muzzlevelocity < 1500){
        muzzlevelocity = 1500;
    }

    if(muzzlevelocity > 1650){
        muzzlevelocity = 1650;
    }
```

I occasionally (although very rarely) achieve a result which lies between 1500 and 1650 inclusive.  Is there another (simpler/more straightforward) way that my desired result could be achieved?

Example outputs are as follows:

Output 1 of 3:

```
Random Angle: 25.0
Random Muzzle Velocity: 1500.0
```

Output 2 of 3:

```
Random Angle: 30.0
Random Muzzle Velocity: 1573.0
```

Output 3 of 3:

```
Random Angle: 43.0
Random Muzzle Velocity: 1500.0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've got it backwards; you want

```
rand.nextInt(151) + 1500
```

to create 150 different values starting at 1500. Note I've used 151, not 150, since you want to include the upper bound. The "if/else" are completely unnecesary; all the values will be in the range you want.

Answer (score 4):

This code is badly broken; there are <strike>25</strike> 26 chances in 55 that 25 will be produced - not at all "random".

You want something like:

```
public int random(Random rnd, int min, int max) {
    if(min>max) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid range - "+min+" > "+max); }
    return (rnd.nextInt(max+1-min)+min);
    }
```

And you can use this for both of your random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry, I've worked it out - I changed all of the above (for muzzlevelocity) to the following and it did the trick:

```
double muzzlevelocity = rand.nextInt(1651 - 1500) + 1500;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should accept the other answers here even though you solved it yourself as they are fixes to your problem